# mouse events in JfreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I need a way to distinguish when a mouse event occurs in the chart itself and not in the chartPanel (the plot area).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the mouse event from your panel and use `ChartMouseEvent.getEntity()` to find if your chart is over one of the chart entities. See the api docs for [ChartMouseEvent](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseEvent.html).